# How to display post in the form of blog system according to post id

Tags: php, database

I have a menu on the left side of my page which lists all the titles of posts.

**menu.inc.php**

```
<?php $rArticles = selectArticles($conn); ?>

<ul class="menu">
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rArticles)){ ?> 
<li><a href="index.php?page=articleform"><?php echo $row['artTitre'];?></a></li>

 <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

What I would like to happen is that when I click on the title, the post will be displayed on this page:

```
<?php $rArticles = selectArticles($conn); ?>

 <h2>Articles <span><a class="btn" href="index.php?page=articleform">Ajouter un article</a></span></h2>


<div class="article">
  <h3>

            <?php 
                $rows =  mysqli_fetch_array($rArticles);
                $rArticlesId = selectArticleById( $rows['artID'], $conn); 
               while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rArticlesId)){ 
            ?>
 <a href="index.php?page=articleform&article=<?php echo $rows['artID']?>">  <?php  echo $rows['artTitre'];  ?></a>

    <span><a class="btn" href="index.php?page=articles&action=delete&item=<?php echo $rows['artID'];?>">supprimer</a></span>
    </h3>
    <p><em><?php  echo $rows['artDate'];  ?> - <?php  echo $rows['artAuteur'];  ?></em></hp>
    <p><?php  echo $rows['artContenu'];  ?></p> 

    <fieldset>
        <legend> Commentaires </legend>
            <?php 
            $rComm = selectCommentairesByIdArticle( $rows['artID'], $conn);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rComm)){ 
            ?>
            <p>
            <a href="index.php?page=commentaires&action=delete&item=<?php echo $row['commentID'];?>"><img src="images/cross.png" /></a>

            <strong><?php  echo $row['commentPseudo'];  ?> </strong><?php  echo $row['commentText'];  ?>
            </p>
            <?php } ?>
        <form action="index.php?page=commentaires&action=insert" method="post">

        <table class="admin_form" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

            <tr>
                <td width="30%"><label for="PseudoCommentaire">Pseudo</label></td>
                <td><input id="PseudoCommentaire" type="text" name="PseudoCommentaire" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['PseudoCommentaire'])) ?> " /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top"><label for="TexteCommentaire">Commentaire</label></td>
                <td><textarea id="TexteCommentaire" name="TexteCommentaire"><?php if(isset($_POST['TextCommentaire'])) ?></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>    
                <td>

                <input type="hidden" name="IdArticle" value="<?php echo $rows['artID'] ?>" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Envoyer le commentaire" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
    </fieldset>
<?php } ?>

</div>
```

I managed to "Delete" and "Add" post, but failed in displaying and editing according to the post ID. My database connection and queries are working fine. I think the problem is directing to the page. Could you please enlighten me on this?

Comment: I think that you need to pass as parameter the post id, it seems that you're not passing it with the href link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For the menu.inc.php** 
Edited: `<a href="index.php?page=home&article=<?php echo $rows['artID'];?>">`

```
<?php 
$rArticles = selectArticles($conn); ?>

<ul class="menu">
<?php while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($rArticles)){ ?> 
<li><a href="index.php?page=home&article=<?php echo $rows['artID'];?>"><?php echo $rows['artTitre'];?></a></li>

<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Then I made another form for editing articles: articleformupdate.php

```
<?php $id = (int)$_GET['article'];
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM articles WHERE artID = \''.$id.'\'';
$rArticle = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($rArticle);

?>
<h2>Articles</h2>
<form action="index.php?page=articles&action=update" method="post">

<table class="admin_form" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

<tr>
    <td width="30%"><label for="TitreArticle">Titre</label></td>
    <td><input id="TitreArticle" type="text" name="TitreArticle" value="<?php 
        if(isset($_POST['TitreArticle'])){ 
            echo ($_POST['TitreArticle']); 
        }else{ 
            echo $row['artTitre'];
        }
        ?>" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="30%"><label for="AuteurArticle">Auteur</label></td>
    <td><input id="AuteurArticle" type="text" name="AuteurArticle" value="<?php 
        if(isset($_POST['AuteurArticle'])){ 
            echo ($_POST['AuteurArticle']); 
        }else{ 
            echo $row['artAuteur'];
        }
        ?>" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td valign="top"><label for="ContenuArticle">Contenu de l'article</label></td>
    <td><textarea id="ContenuArticle" name="ContenuArticle"><?php 
    if(isset($_POST['ContenuArticle'])){  
        echo ($_POST['ContenuArticle']);
    }else{ 
        echo $row['artContenu'];
    }  ?></textarea></td>

  </tr>
<tr>    
    <td> 
    <input type="hidden" name="dateArticle" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="IdArticle" value="<?php 
        if(isset($_POST['IdArticle'])){ 
            echo ($_POST['IdArticle']); 
        }else{ 
            echo $row['artID'];
        } ?>" />
       </td>

       <td>
        <a class="btn" href="index.php">Annuler</a>
        <input type="submit"  value="Envoyer" />
       </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

**menu.inc.php**

```
<?php $rArticles = selectArticles($conn); ?>

<ul class="menu">
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rArticles)){ ?> 

 <li>
   <a href="index.php?page=articleform&post_id=<?php echo $row['YOUR-POST-ID'];?>">
     <?php echo $row['artTitre'];?>
   </a>
 </li>

<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

And in display/edit page

```
$post_id = $_GET['post_id']
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way of doing this is adding your unique parameter from

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($rArticles)
```

To your menu generation. Assuming that your unique parameter is named 'id', is a primary key with auto increment and is returned by your query, it would be:

```
<?php $rArticles = selectArticles($conn); ?>

<ul class="menu">
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rArticles)){ ?> 
<li><a href="index.php?page=articleform&article=<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><?php echo $row['artTitre'];?></a></li>

 <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Then on the next page you could request your data from the database using (simplified form):

```
$id = (int)$_GET['article'];
$sql = "SELECT data FROM table WHERE id=$id LIMIT 1"; // place your SQL here
$rArticle = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($rArticle);
```